# Remote debugging with XDebug and PHPStorm

Tags: xdebug, phpstorm

First things first:

- Server is an Apache running on Debian in a VMPlayer
- Host is Windows 7
- Debugging-Server is XDebug
- Files are directly accessible via a shared folder

*Important*: XDebug is properly configured on Apache and my Win7 firewall as well. **I know that b/c I can debug using Eclipse**.

So what I am failing at seems to be the basic configuration of PHPStorm.

Let me give you some more details:

- IP of Server: 192.168.56.128
- IP of my host: 192.168.56.1

the file that I want to debug is index.php:

- location on my Win7 host: C:\dev\sf\Symfony\
- location on Debian: \mnt\hgfs\sf\Symfony\
- URL: 192.168.56.128/Symfony/index.php

No matter what I fiddle together ... I get weired error messages like "Waiting for connection from JetBrains PhpStorm..." or PHPStorm asks me for Mozillas profile.ini, even though I configured Chrome as Default in Web Browsers.

So I will just set up a new project and hopefully someone tells me what is wrong with my configuration.

**Run / Edit configurations / Defaults / PHP Remote Debugging**:

- Server: "Debian"
- IDE key: -
- Break at first line: yes

**Servers**:

- Name: "Debian"
- Host: 192.168.56.128
- Port: 80
- Debugger: Xdebug
- use path mappings: yes
- one path mapping configured:

C:\dev\sf\Symfony => /mnt/hgfs/sf/Symfony (also tried /Symfony - b/c PHPStorm shouldn't care about anything above /Symfony !?)

**Run / Edit configurations / Defaults / PHP Web Application**:

- Server: "Debian"
- Start URL: /Symfony
- Browser: Chrome
- Break on first line: yes

Now I choose: Run / Debug ... / 1.index.php

And I get asked for: Mozilla's profile.ini ... but I can't find it

Where is it ... ?

I already got so far that PHPStorm started Chrome. But maybe I first sort this out. So how can I get Firefox up and running? I also use Firefox with Eclipse ... no questions asked for a profile.ini.

Comment: Full guide here: [How to debug code on a remote server (or in vagrant box) with PHPStorm](http://www.dev-metal.com/debug-code-remote-server-vagrant-box-phpstorm/)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Okay, there are three things I'd like to share with you. It's not the full recipe but the key ingredients that were first confusing me are:

1. The important sections to configure are **"Servers"** and **"PHP Remote Debugging"**.
2. To configure "PHP Remote Debugging" you have to first **add a new dataset** using the [+] in the top left corner. The panel you get from just clicking on the "PHP R D"-button just keeps the *default settings*!
3. Absolute path regarding the VM actually means the **absolute path starting from root** (\mnt\hgfs\sf\Symfony). This was confusing to me cause I am still not sure why PhpStorm cares about directory levels above the shared folder. but it does.

Comment: You just rescued me after 3/4 of a day of work getting remote debugging with this stuff, that I absolutely NEEDED working, by SUCCINCTLY stating what they were looking for with the absolute path portion.  I had originally thought the same thing you did.  Thank you kindly sir!

Comment: Just in case, do not forget to set xdebug.remote_host param. By default seems to be pointing to localhost.

Answer (score 7):

If you are still having problems, there are two blog posts by the makers on how to set things up correctly.

First should work in most cases and requires [zero-configuration](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Zero-configuration+Web+Application+Debugging+with+Xdebug+and+PhpStorm) other than a working xdebug install

Second details all of the [configuration settings in detail](http://blog.jetbrains.com/webide/2011/03/configure-php-debugging-in-phpstorm-2-0/)

Comment: [Up-to-date zero-configuration manual moved here](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Zero-configuration+Web+Application+Debugging+with+Xdebug+and+PhpStorm)

Answer (score 1):

To 'see' the `profile.ini` in the PHP Storm 'Select File' Dialog simply rightclick inside of it and choose 'Show hidden files' then (in WIn7) move to `C:\Users\YOURUSERNAME\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox` or the equivalent in your OS

Comment: the thing is, that eventually I didn't need that file at all, anyway.

Comment: stating a part of your question: "profile.ini ... but I can't find it
Where is it ... ?" .. searching took me here and i missed a comment like mine..

Answer (score -1):

1. Ensure that remote debugging is enabled in php.ini

   xdebug.remote_enable = 1
2. Your server "192.168.56.128" should be in  **PHP-> Servers**
3. Add **PHP Web Application** Debug Configuration, and use added server
4. Set a breakpoint and start debugging using this configuration

Comment: -1 for not reading my question: (1) as I said, I can remote debug with Eclipse - so it is enabled (2) see description (3) see description (4) see description ...#