# Phpstorm + xdebug : Remote host is configured as "localhost" despite server host is probably not local

Tags: debugging, phpstorm, xdebug, remote-debugging

I was following this [instruction](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Validating+Your+Debugging+Configuration) to validate my debugger configuration on Web Server. I uses a remote server whose FTP connection has been tested, but I get this warning message saying

> Remote host is configured as 'localhost' despite server host is probably not local

[image]

My first question is: what does "remote host" and "server host" refer to respectively?

I know remote host is the setting `xdebug.remote_host`, and according to the [xdebug documentation](https://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#remote_host), it is "the host where the debug client is running".

This makes me confused: Isn't the debug client the IDE I am running on my local machine?

If yes, then shouldn't "the host where the debug client is running" be my local machines's IP address? If yes again, should I configure `xdebug.remote_host` to be my IP?

I tried setting it to my IP, the warning message does't show but it doesn't feel right because later I tried it with a random IP the message also doesn't show.

Secondly, the [xdebug documentation](https://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#remote_host) also says that this `xdebug.remote_host` setting will be ignored if `xdebug.remote_connect_back` is enabled." Although not quite sure what this setting does, I set it to be "On", as the picture shows:
[image]

I was hoping this will eliminate the warning message, but it is still there. So how do I get rid of this message?

Comment: 1) If you have your xdebug installed **on remote server** then `remote_host` should have an IP of your computer where PhpStorm is running **as sees from that remote server**. For that you need to ensure that xdebug port is opened on your firewall/router -- in other words -- that xdebug is able to connect to your computer (because that's exactly how it works -- https://xdebug.org/docs/remote). 2) `remote_connect_back` can be dangerous -- anyone who will issue "debug this" commend will be able to communicate with your xdebug. But if you are happy to use it .. then you can ignore what IDE says.

Comment: Thank you. You are answering my questions. If I prove what you said, then this should be the answer.

Comment: 3) If you can establish SSH connection to your server .. then you can use debugging over SSH and in such case the `remote_host` has to be local IP (e.g. 127.0.0.1) 4) `remote_connect_back` can be OK to use when server in in LAN (e.g VM or physical server somewhere next to you)

Comment: The documentation is in severe need of an overhaul. The issues with local machine and "remote server" are not only for you.

Answer (score 13):

In my case, I had several apache virtual hosts setup for different projects. I was able to access projects via different urls, like : `http://projectname1`, `http://anotherproject2` .

I was getting that same error in PhpStorm while doing xdebug validation:

> Remote host is configured as “localhost” despite server host is
>   probably not local

Problem was fixed, once in php.ini `xdebug.remote_host` matched the URL of the project I was debugging. So, if I was debugging `http://project1`, I would have this in php.ini:

```
xdebug.remote_host="project1"
```

Having values as 127.0.0.1, or localhost didn't fix it.

Hope it helps someone.

Comment: I have similar setup as yours using vagrant + homestead and I followed your advice. Though the error message never went away, it didn't seem to hinder me debugging remotely. I could place a breakpoint and it would break as expected. Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with following?

> xdebug.remote_host = "127.0.0.1"

Comment: Change the debugger setting on phpStorm as (Local web server or shared folder). Anyhow its going to be debugged in localhost.

Comment: I wanna do remote debugging, was following this https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Remote+debugging+in+PhpStorm+via+SSH+tunnel

Comment: But, as of your phpinfo(), you have set up xdebug locally. possibly the following link might help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7234471/remote-debugging-with-xdebug-and-phpstorm?rq=1

Comment: because previously you specified the remote_host as localhost. Where did you set up xdebug? if not in localhost, use the correct IP of the machine, and check if the port 9000 is accessible. (try "telnet host 9000" to on command prompt to check it is accessible)

Comment: xDebug is installed on remote server. I set `xdebug.remote_host` to its IP, and the validation went through. But I am still very confused with those questions I asked in my main question.

Comment: the php.ini where you run application from, should refer the xdebug.remote_host to where the xdebug is installed. All good if resolved.

Comment: I did that. But this is only the beginning to remote debugging